# Why does my SwiftUI app jump back to the previous view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created an iOS app with SwiftUI and Swift. The purpose is as follows:

1. User enters an address into an input field (`AddressInputView`)
2. On submit, the app switches to `ResultView` and passes the address

**Problem:** The `ResultView` is visible for just a split second and then suddenly jumps back to `AddressInputView`.

**Question:** Why is the app jumping back to the previous view (Instead of staying in ResultView) and how can the code be adjusted to fix the issue?

My Code:

---

**StartView.swift**

```
struct StartView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            AddressInputView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**AddressInputView.swift**

```
enum Destination {
    case result
}

struct AddressInputView: View {
    @State private var address: String = ""
    @State private var experiences: [Experience] = []
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: $address, prompt: Text("Search address"))
                    .onSubmit {
                        path.append(Destination.result)
                    }
                Button("Submit") {
                    path.append(Destination.result)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self, destination: { destination in
                    switch destination {
                        case .result:
                            ResultView(address: $address, experiences: $experiences)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ExperienceModels.swift**

```
struct ExperienceServiceResponse: Codable {
    let address: String
    let experiences: [Experience]
}
```

---

**ResultView.swift**

```
struct ResultView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Binding private var address: String
    @Binding private var experiences: [Experience]

    init(address: Binding<String>, experiences: Binding<[Experience]>) {
        _address = Binding(projectedValue: address)
        _experiences = Binding(projectedValue: experiences)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Results")
                    ForEach(experiences, id: \.name) { experience in
                        ResultTile(experience: experience)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This happens because of some change in your previous view. If you have a **@Published var** in the previous view and somehow it is changing its value causing your view to pop back

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve], there is _way_ too much code above. Some simple testing would have shown you that the problem wasn't in the `fetch()` method, so why include that? If that's not needed, then why the `submit()` method, etc.

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks for your suggestion. I simplified the code above.

Comment: @TimoErnst, thank you, that's much better. In future I'd also recommend putting all the code in one block so it's easier to copy and paste directly into Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `NavigationStack`s. This is a container view that should be containing your view hierarchy, not something that is declared at every level. So, amend your start view:

```
struct StartView: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            AddressInputView(path: $path)
        }
    }
}
```

`AddressInputView` should take the path as a binding:

```
@Binding var path: NavigationPath
```

And you should remove `NavigationStack` from the body of that view. Likewise with `ResultView`. I made these changes in a project using the code you posted and the issue was fixed.

I'm not sure exactly why your view is popping back but you're essentially pushing a navigation view onto a navigation view onto a navigation view, so it's not entirely surprising the system gets confused.